# How do I get udev to mount certain USB disks when they are plugged in, or after a reboot?

Tags: fedora, udev

I've just upgraded to Fedora 15.  I've used [Bacula](http://www.bacula.org/en/) for backup for some years now, and it works fine.  But now I've just run into a problem, probably because Bacula is now running as user bacula rather than as root.

My backup media is two USB disk drives (I keep one offsite and swap them over once a month or so).  However Fedora auto-mounts the USB drive with its mount point owned by my UID with mode 700, presumably because I am logged in and this would be the Right Thing for most USB storage.  However in this case it is not because Bacula can't access it.

If I understand the sequence of events correctly, udev creates the /dev/sdb and /dev/sdb1 device nodes, and these are then automounted by udisk (which is a Gnome component).  It's udisk that decides what the mount parameters are.

What I want is for any disk labelled "BACKUP*" to be mounted with its mount point owned by bacula:bacula, mode 700.  I think I need a custom udev rule file in /etc/udev/rules.d.  I've read the udev(7) page and "[Writing udev rules](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)".  Here is what I have come up with so far, in a file called "10-backup-disk.rules".  It's being parsed by udev OK, but isn't working: the disk still winds up being owned by me.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
KERNEL!="sd[a-z][0-9]", GOTO="backup-disk_auto_mount_end"
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="BACKUP*", GOTO="backup-disk_auto_mount_end"

# Import FS infos
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"

# Get disk label
ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_LABEL}"

# Global mount options
ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="relatime,rw"
# Filesystem-specific mount options
ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="$env{mount_options}"

# Mount the device
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/%E{dir_name}"

# Clean up after removal
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/%E{dir_name}"

# Exit
LABEL="backup-disk_auto_mount_end"
```

Answer (score 6):

I know nothing about *udev*, but since you're using Fedora 15 you can accomplish the same thing with *systemd* much more simply.

Assuming you have a USB drive labeled BACKUP_ONE, create the following file:

`/etc/systemd/system/mnt-backup1.mount`:

```
[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-label/BACKUP_ONE
Where=/mnt/backup1
Options=uid=bacula,gid=bacula,mode=0700
```

Note the filename must end in `.mount` and have a name that matches the mount point (in the `Where=` line of the unit file), with slashes (`/`) changed to dashes (`-`).  For more information, see [`man systemd.unit`](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/systemd.unit.html).

Additionally, you can prevent it from mounting the drive until Bacula actually runs a backup (or you try to access the drive) by creating `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-backup1.automount`:

```
[Automount]
Where=/mnt/backup1
[Install]
WantedBy=remote-fs.target
```

Repeat this for your other drive, and then run `systemctl enable mnt-backup1.automount` and `systemctl daemon-reload` to inform *systemd* of the changes.  (I'd make sure they're unplugged at this time so it doesn't get confused.)

*udisks* will now defer to your *systemd* configuration and mount it with the options you defined.